Android Leanback DatePicker not focusing
I am trying to use the leanback Date picker that the system Guided Steps use. Pictured here:  Guided Step DatePicker Implementation
However, when I try to add the same component that they use (androidx.leanback.widget.picker.DatePicker) It does not focus no matter what I try.
Here it is wrapped in a simple frameLayout for my prototyping purposes.
The Fragment it is attached to is a regular Fragment and is requesting focus on view creation.

        <FrameLayout
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <androidx.leanback.widget.picker.DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/date_picker"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:spinnersShown="true"
                android:focusable="true">
            </androidx.leanback.widget.picker.DatePicker>
        </FrameLayout>


I like the design of this component and would like to use it over using multiple NumberPickers.
Tried: Wrapping in different leanback views. Did not make a difference in the focusability.
